# Get active weeks from start and end date

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have subscriptions data as shown below. The data shows when a user bought a subscription. It has `user_id,subscription_id,start date and end_date`.

I have derived `wk_start` and `wk_end` from it.

```
+------+-----------------+------------+------------+----------+--------+
| user | subscription_id |   start    |    end     | wk_start | wk_end |
+------+-----------------+------------+------------+----------+--------+
|    1 | 1A              | 2019-06-01 | 2019-06-30 |       22 |     27 |
|    2 | 2A              | 2019-06-01 | 2019-06-21 |       22 |     25 |
|    3 | 3A              | 2019-06-01 | 2019-06-21 |       22 |     24 |
|    1 | 1B              | 2019-07-04 | 2019-08-04 |       27 |     29 |
|    2 | 2B              | 2019-07-01 | 2019-07-31 |       27 |     31 |
+------+-----------------+------------+------------+----------+--------+
```

Now I want to transform the data in a such a way that for each `user,subscription_id`, I will get the active weeks for a particular user.

The desired output is as below

```
+------+-----------------+------+
| user | subscription_id | Week |
+------+-----------------+------+
|    1 | 1A              |   22 |
|    1 | 1A              |   23 |
|    1 | 1A              |   24 |
|    1 | 1A              |   25 |
|    1 | 1A              |   26 |
|    1 | 1A              |   27 |
|    2 | 2A              |   22 |
|    2 | 2A              |   23 |
|    2 | 2A              |   24 |
|    2 | 2A              |   25 |
|    3 | 3A              |   22 |
|    3 | 3A              |   23 |
|    3 | 3A              |   24 |
|    1 | 1B              |   27 |
|    1 | 1B              |   28 |
|    1 | 1B              |   29 |
|    2 | 2B              |   27 |
|    2 | 2B              |   28 |
|    2 | 2B              |   29 |
|    2 | 2B              |   30 |
|    2 | 2B              |   31 |
+------+-----------------+------+
```

It basically expands the subscriptions data to get *active* weeks for each user.

For example `user 1` with `subscription_id 1A` was active from week 22 till 27.

Similarly `user 2` with `subscription_id 2A` was active from week 22 till 25.

Now `user 2` was again active from week 27 till 31 with  `subscription_id 2B`

I hope this helps to understand the desired result

I have made a [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mn4towXxscmLsibQjwtNEH/0) here.(though it's in mysql) but should help in some or the other way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a table that includes all week numbers and do a partial cartesian join against it, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE weeks (
  `week` INTEGER 
);

INSERT INTO weeks
  (`week`)
VALUES
         (1),  (2),  (3),  (4),  (5),  (6),  (7),  (8),  (9)
, (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19)
, (20), (21), (22), (23), (24), (25), (26), (27), (28), (29)
, (30), (31), (32), (33), (34), (35), (36), (37), (38), (39)
, (40), (41), (42), (43), (44), (45), (46), (47), (48), (49)
, (50), (51), (52), (53)
;

SELECT t1.user, t1.subscription_id, w.week
FROM table1 t1
CROSS JOIN weeks w
WHERE w.week BETWEEN t1.wk_start and t1.wk_end
ORDER BY t1.user, t1.subscription_id, w.week;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mn4towXxscmLsibQjwtNEH/0

The weeks table seems like a bit of a nuisance, but it just has to be created once and then you can forget about it.

Comment: select user_id,subscription_id,wk_start+pe.i from db.test_week
lateral view posexplode(split(space(wk_end - wk_start),' ')) pe as i,s
;

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
select user,subscription_id, t.wk_end - pe.i as week
from (
select 1 as user, "1A" as subscription_id , 22 as wk_start, 27 as wk_end
union all  
select 2 as user, "2A" as subscription_id , 22 as wk_start, 25 as wk_end
union all  
select 3 as user, "3A" as subscription_id , 22 as wk_start, 24 as wk_end
union all  
select 1 as user, "1B" as subscription_id , 27 as wk_start, 29 as wk_end
union all  
select 2 as user, "2B" as subscription_id , 27 as wk_start, 31 as wk_end
) t
lateral view posexplode(split(space(wk_end - wk_start),' ')) pe as i,s
;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use in-memory stack and join with it:

```
with weeks as(
select stack (53, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
                  21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,
                  41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53  
) as week_number
)

SELECT t1.user, t1.subscription_id, w.week_number
  FROM table1 t1
       CROSS JOIN weeks w
 WHERE w.week_number BETWEEN t1.wk_start and t1.wk_end
 ORDER BY t1.user, t1.subscription_id, w.week_number;
```

Also you can generate weeks, this also will work fast:

```
with weeks as(
select i week_number 
from(select posexplode(split(space(53),' ')) as (i,x)) s  
)
```

And one more method using array + explode:

```
with weeks as(
select explode(array (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
                  21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,
                  41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53)) as week_number
)
```